# Problemas ao salvar arquivo XML com caractere especial no banco (ç, ã, etc)

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

Meu problema é o seguinte:
Eu estou fazendo a emissão de uma carta de correção eletrônica em C# e na hora de salvar o XML do evento retornado pela SEFAZ, por mais que todos os caracteres do arquivo estejam normais, na hora de salvar no banco como blob eles ficam assim, com esses caracteres estranhos ("xE7, xE3") quando eu exporto o arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Edit1: E quando eu tento dar load nesse xml com esses caracteres estranhos ele lança XmlException reclamando de caractere inválido

Comment: Qual o tipo de dados da coluna onde esta salvando esse Xml?

Comment: o tipo de dados da coluna é longblob

Comment: o collation é latin-swedish_ci, imagino que seja isso

Comment: Os caracteres estão trucados seu banco de  dados não suporta utf-8 ou caracteres latin.

Comment: Coloca como utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema fazendo um Encoding.Convert de latin1 pra utf-8 antes de dar WriteAllBytes, ai ele veio certinho e não deu mais erro na hora de dar Load por caractere inválido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: OBS: A solução é misturada(VB e C#), por isso o arquivo que eu acabei resolvendo foi em VB, eu tava tentando resolver na parte em C#

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando que você esta utilizando o NotePad++ vá no menu Codificação e altere de UTF-8 para ANSI, não será a solução do seu problema, mas lhe mostrará o resultado com os caracteres corretos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifique os arquivos do seu sistema, esta tendo uma incompatibilidade entre o seu projeto e os dados que você recebe, um esta com ANSI (provavelmente o seu) e o outro como UTF-8